# Does Heal end Sanctuary when fighting undead?

Tags: spells, undead, pathfinder-2e

I am fighting undead creatures and have [Sanctuary](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=266) on me. If I use [Heal](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=148) does that end Sanctuary?

Comment: Are you using Heal to damage undead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Yes*

Assuming you mean using [Heal](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=148) to damage undead, then yes. There is nothing in [Sanctuary](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=266) that excludes hostile actions that target undead. Damaging is 100% a hostile action, and, per Sanctuary:

> If the target uses a hostile action, the spell ends.

The rules for [hostile actions](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=300) state that:

> A hostile action is one that can harm or damage another creature...

So using Heal to damage undead qualifies.

Note: This does mean you can still use Heal (in any of its variants) to target your allies for healing, though, without breaking Sanctuary.

Comment: May want to throw a link in about Pathfinder 2e's definition of "Hostile Actions", particularly, "A hostile action is one that can harm or damage another creature" - https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=300

Comment: @brandon that's an excellent idea, thank you! I had no idea that rule even existed, I'm glad it's defined.